# Networkx: how can i import a graph from a file?

Tags: python, networkx

With  networkx, im  trying to import a graph from a txt file.

The graph format is this (ex:):

```
a b 
a c 
b d 
c e
```

Thtat means: `a--b  a--c  b--d c--e`

I suppose this is an edge list so i tried use the appropriate command:

```
G=nx.read_edgelist("path\file.txt")
```

but it doesen't work, any ideas?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Was there any error returned? I just tried this minimal example and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import networkx as nx

with open('a.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

myList = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]
# [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'e']]

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(myList)

print g.nodes()
# ['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd']
print g.edges()
# [('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'e'), ('b', 'd')]
```